# Is it possible to provide a setter function in my computational expression?

Tags: multithreading, functional-programming, f#, thread-safety

I'm trying to write an F# computational expression that permits reading and writing thread-safe variables only from within a critical section.

I've got a type, `ThreadSafeVar<'t>` that wraps a value, a `CriticalSection<'t>` and a computational expression builder, `LockContext`, as follows:

```
// wraps a value and restricts access to it
type ThreadSafeVar<'t> (value: 't) =
  member val internal Value = value with get, set

// Encapsulates a critical section
type CriticalSection<'t> =
  private
    { LockObj: obj
      fn: unit -> 't }
    
  static member Lock(lc: CriticalSection<'t>) = lock lc.LockObj lc.fn

// Expression builder for a locked context
type LockContext () =
  member internal this.SyncRoot = obj()
  member this.Return(value: 'v) = value
  member this.ReturnFrom(value: ThreadSafeVar<'t>) = value.Value
  member __.Bind(value: ThreadSafeVar<'t>, fn: 't -> 'u) = fn value.Value
  // returns a CriticalSection
  member this.Run(fn : unit -> 'u) = { LockObj = this.SyncRoot
                                       fn=fn }
  .
  .
  .
```

Reading the thread-safe values from within a lock context is simple enough thanks to `Bind`. e.g.

```
  let lockedInt = ThreadSafeVar(1) // create a thread-safe variable
  let context = LockContext()
  let wrapperVal = context {
                     let! i = lockedInt // get the wrapper value inside lockedInt 
                     return i 
                   } |> CriticalSection.Lock
```

But I'm struggling to understand how to implement a means setting the value from within a `LockContext` instance. The approach I've thus taken is to implement a [custom operation](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-customoperationattribute.html) called, for instance, `setVal`. I've included my attempts thus far but I'm afraid they'd just muddy the waters. It seems that custom operations operate upon the computation built so far within the expression, encoded as a tuple, but I don't see that this is required in my case.

Any hints, pointing to resources, or direct help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not at all sure of the wisdom of this, but I came up with something based on the [State monad](https://dev.to/shimmer/the-state-monad-in-f-3ik0) that might work for you. First, define a "stateful" function as one that takes a `ThreadSafeVar` and returns some type of result:

```ml
ThreadSafeVar<'state> -> 'result
```

We then put that signature into a type that represents a stateful computation:

```ml
type Stateful<'state, 'result> =
    MkStateful of (ThreadSafeVar<'state> -> 'result)
```

Now we need a way to run such a computation safely using a given TSV:

```ml
let run (tsv : ThreadSafeVar<_>) (MkStateful f) =
    lock tsv (fun () -> f tsv)
```

Note that I've gotten rid of your `CriticalSection` type and instead just lock the TSV itself.

Next, we need a way to lift a pure value into a stateful computation:

```ml
let lift value =
    MkStateful (fun _ -> value)
```

And a way to bind two stateful computations together:

```ml
let bind binder stateful =
    MkStateful (fun tsv ->
        run tsv stateful
            |> binder
            |> run tsv)
```

Defining the builder is then trivial:

```ml
type LockContext () =
    member __.Return(value) = lift value
    member __.Bind(stateful, binder) = bind binder stateful

let context = LockContext()
```

We also need helper computations for setting and getting a value safely:

```ml
let getValue =
    MkStateful (fun tsv ->
        tsv.Value)

let setValue value =
    MkStateful (fun tsv ->
        tsv.Value <- value)
```

Putting it all together, we can define a computation that increments the value of a TSV:

```ml
let comp =
    context {
        let! oldValue = getValue
        let newValue = oldValue + 1
        do! setValue newValue
        return newValue
    }
```

And we can run it like this:

```ml
let lockedInt = ThreadSafeVar(1)
let result = comp |> run lockedInt
printfn "%A" result   // output is: 2
```

You can see the full solution and try it yourself [here](https://try.fsharp.org/#?code=C4TwDgpgBAKgFgJwgQwCYGVkDMIDVkIA8A5MAHxQAUAbsgDYCuEAXFKQJRQC8AsAFBRBUALYRhAIwgIotOlACWAO2BTF9KPkbQuM+kygB3ecDhQA5hGAAaKAGdL-fqEhR0wZCqwM6JW+5U2xEi23uTc-EJQALIA1m4eEF5yAPZYVPBIaJg4+ETEfgkUALQUQRAhdMDsjnx0llAIDIpUwLbUUKwZKBjYeASEAPpknJSx8Z7eUFicvAJCdMkAxjFQre2UXs2UnCVTq23VfPx1wFB08linsvqzkWP+iZMbTVADULvXEIfH9eJKqFA-opUFI7A8kuE5oJ7gkIc9mmt3mQIpEhI0EW0wbDvCjUaiAD4UIEghC4vFCQkNF5rb58ZzQAAySxiAGFksoIAAPU7bSGRUQSUEDAYAOgASpYGAhFDQ9F9uGcLlc5WSBZJpMKRQAhf6UAoTOg2YlSGaA-5m4Gg-WPOg1E5QRbslTchVM5Zsjnc7Z2+oWYCaG5kmEGqibfbtEpkyJrEUBr4+072f1y3RaPlCYM20PUzGRqGomNxqCEIqppi0+2O4RgdOCR2e04Abyj80sAEIoMk6Kgizo-XGW4J7YoIAZe53u0WANRQACMg6gqGSHaTRZHY5V+ciSGAUua64H+YAvj9TgtlhBUABJZQKrpZXq5Sizw724KhBVVmuU9FnZmXm9gH4MAECUYAsGaAAiABSABBSCGnKUJ+CAA&html=DwCwLgtgNgfAsAKAAQqaApgQwCb2ag4CdMTJcMABwFp0BHAVwEsA3AXgCIBhAewDsw6AdQAqAT0roOSAMb9BAzoIAeYAPThoAbhkhMAJwDOJNgzAAzagA4OeQhqy5EhAEY9sYu6mBq3HvD6asEA&css=Q).